# what can I use to convert speech to text (offline)?

Tags: python, offline, speech-to-text

I want to know what libraries are there to convert any voice to text locally (offline). Even if the word is incomprehensible or meaningless (Literally translate words) in python.

Comment: what would these "incomprehensible" sounds be turned into?

Comment: I want it to convert to text

Comment: this is difficult because speech is made up of "phonemes" and these are mostly unrelated to written text.  maybe you could explain your problem better which would help us give better answers.  alternatively you could try something like https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: my english is not clear i will try to explan as i can.
ok i know that there is a solutions to convert speech to text but i have a question about this solutions : for exempels Google Cloud Speech API can convert any speech (for exempels blablablablabla ) to text or it use some algorithems to find the right text that humens can understand and if it the speech is not enogh clear this API don't convert it ?

Comment: I think I was maybe interpreting "incomprehensible or meaningless" in a way you didn't intend.  that said, doing speech recognition offline is difficult and modern high-quality engines tend to be large (i.e. many GB) and hence it's often more efficient to leave them on dedicated servers and move the (smaller) audio data/files around..  this site is about solving problems with specific bits of code, and isn't great for general questions.  hence my suggestion to try one of the sites that is likely to give answers rather than closing the question as off-topic

Comment: ok thank you so it will be better to try this sites  softwarerecs.stackexchange.com and datascience.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/). CMU Sphinx will work offline but may not be as efficient.